# Make a field mandatory, only if another field is null in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

Assuming the following action class that can handle file uploading.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value="struts-default")
public final class CategoryAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, ModelDriven<Category>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private File fileUpload;
    private String fileUploadContentType;
    private String fileUploadFileName;

    private Long editId;

    //Getters and setters.

    @Validations(
            requiredFields={
                @RequiredFieldValidator(fieldName="fileUpload", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Uploading an image is mandatory.")})
    @Action(value = "AddCategory",
        results = {
            @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Category", "currentPage", "${currentPage}", "message", "${message}", "editId", "${editId}", "status", "${status}"}),
            @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Category.jsp")},
        interceptorRefs={
            @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "editId, fileUpload, fileUploadContentType, fileUploadFileName, catId, catName, visible, latest, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
        })
    public String insertOrUpdate(){
        //Do either insert or update based on editId.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "Category",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Category.jsp"),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Category.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "id, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, message, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String load() throws Exception{
        //This method is just required to return an initial view on page load.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I would like to validate `fileUpload` (mandatory) only when `editId` is `null`. If it is initialized to a `Long` value then, this validation should not be performed and excluded. `editId` is supplied as a query-string parameter while editing a row held by an HTML table.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not mention very precisely in the question where this kind of validation is needed. Actually, I wanted to validate a `java.io.File` field in an action class.

While inserting a row into the database (there is a common submit button, `<s:submit>` for both insert and update operations), this file (actually an image file) is mandatory but while editing/updating a row, uploading of an image is completely optional. It may or may not be uploaded through a file browse. Therefore, while updating a row, this validation should not be performed (other kind of validations like file size, invalid file type would be performed, only if a file were to be uploaded).

To overcome this situation, I have gone with `@FieldExpressionValidator` as follows.

```
@Validations(
    fieldExpressions={
            @FieldExpressionValidator(fieldName="fileUpload", expression="editId!=null&&fileUpload==null||editId!=null&&fileUpload!=null||editId==null&&fileUpload!=null", key="file.upload.mandatory")
})
```

This makes an image mandatory while inserting a row but it makes an image optional while updating a row.

<sub>If there are still better alternatives then, please add them as an answer (I may be wrong).</sub>